# What does killed mean, as response to loading a program in Fedora linux?

Tags: linux, assembly, crash

I have an assembler program with a simple structure, a text segment and a bss segment. Similar programs have been compiled by me over a decade. It is a Forth compiler and I play tricks with the elf header.
I'm used to it that if I mess up the elf header, I can't start the program and the loader says "killed" before it even segfaults.

But now I've a user of a Fedora version 6 linux, who does the following:

```
as -32 lina.s
ld a.out -N -melf_i386 -o lina
./lina
```

and get a message "killed" and 137 as result of 'echo $?'

Clearly this procedure uses only official tools, such that the elf header should at least be valid.
The exact same procedure on other systems like my ubuntu or Debian systems lead to programs that work normally. The objdumps of the resulting programs are the same at least what the mapping of segments is concerned.

Please give me some indication of what is going on here, I have no clue of how to tackle this problem.

I'd like to stress that probably no instruction is executed, i.e. gdb refuses to run it. Like so

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/gerard/Desktop/lina-5.1/glina32
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint -2.
Error accessing memory address 0x8048054: Input/output error.
```

(gdb)

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] that reproduces this behaviour that's small enough to post in the question?  Otherwise all we can do is answer the question title.

Comment: That is hard because it requires severe experimenting on a system I've no access to. Actually I'm quite happy with the answer to the question title given by Ross Ridge, that gives direction to the experimenting (should it ever come to that) and marked it with the green tick.

Comment: Yup, Ross's answer makes perfect sense.  My comment was from before it was posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In rare cases if an error occurs while when a process tries to execute a new program the Linux kernel will send a SIGKILL signal to that process instead of returning an error.  That signal will result in the shell printing "Killed", rather than a more useful error message like "out of memory". Something about the executable you've created triggers an error that the kernel can only recover from by killing the process that tried to execute it.

Normally shells execute a program by making two system calls: `fork` and `execve`. The first system call creates a new process, but doesn't load a new executable.  Instead the `fork` system call duplicates the process that invoked it.  The second system call loads a new executable but doesn't create a new process. Instead the program running in the process is replaced by a new program from the executable.

In the process of performing the `execve` system call the kernel needs to discard the previous contents of the process's address space so it can completely replace it with an entirely new one. After this point the `execve` system call can no longer return an error code to the program that invoked it as that program no longer exists. If error occurs after this point which prevents the executable from loading then the kernel has no other option but to kill the process.

This behaviour is documented in the Linux [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) man page:

> In most cases where **execve**() fails, control returns to the original
> executable image, and the caller of **execve**() can then handle the
> error.  However, in (rare) cases (typically caused by resource
> exhaustion), failure may occur past the point of no return: the
> original executable image has been torn down, but the new image could
> not be completely built.  In such cases, the kernel kills the process
> with a **SIGKILL** signal.

Answer (score 1):

The message is printed by bash, according to what signal number terminated the process.  "Killed" means the process received `SIGKILL`:

```
$ pgrep cat  # check that there aren't other cat processes running that you might not want to kill while doing this

$ cat         # in another terminal, pkill cat
Terminated
$ cat         # in another terminal, pkill -9 cat  (or pkill -KILL cat)
Killed
$ cat         #  pkill -QUIT cat   or hit control-\
Quit (core dumped)
$ cat         #  pkill -STOP cat  or hit control-z

[1]+  Stopped                 cat
$ fg
cat                 # pkill -BUS cat
Bus error (core dumped)
$ cat               # pkill -PWR cat
Power failure
```

Bash doesn't print anything for `SIGINT`, because that's what control-C sends.

Run `kill -l` to list signal abbreviations.

```
$ strace cat            # then pkill -KILL cat
... dynamic library opening and mapping, etc. etc.
read(0,  <unfinished ...>)              = ?
+++ killed by SIGKILL +++
Killed
```

---

I can't reproduce your problem with `as -32 hello.s` / `ld -N -melf_i386` to make an executable that my kernel won't run, or that receives SIGKILL right away.

With `gcc -m32 -c` / `ld -N`,  or with `gcc -m32 -E hello.S > hello.s && as -32`, I get a binary that prints Hello World (using sys_write and sys_exit).

```
// hello.S   a simple example I had lying around
// Use  gcc -m32 -E hello.S > hello.s to create input for as -32   
#include <asm/unistd.h>
#include <syscall.h>
#define STDOUT 1

.data               # should really be .rodata
hellostr:
    .ascii "hello wolrd\n";
helloend:

.text
.globl _start

_start:
    movl $(SYS_write) , %eax  //ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
    movl $(STDOUT) , %ebx
    movl $hellostr , %ecx
    movl $(helloend-hellostr) , %edx
    int $0x80

    movl $(SYS_exit), %eax //void _exit(int status);
    xorl %ebx, %ebx
    int $0x80

    ret
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start by using `strace`, to see which syscalls, if any, are issued by the executable, prior to it killing itself.

Looking at the syscalls will often point towards a clue, as to where the problem lies.

Comment: What sections does `lina.s` include? I've seen a bug (ld, I think) in which a .bss section with no .data section produced an executable that the loader wouldn't load (alignment problem, I think). It was reported as a "Nasm bug", but (G)as did it too. As I recall, a different ld solved it. As a workaround, put a .data section in `lina.s` (if it hasn't got one). Wild guess.

Comment: I use  the -N alias -magic for a reason. lina has a bss section,  snug after the .text section, and all sections readable writable and executable. Adding a section is unfortunately not an option, but at least your suggestion helps in experimenting.

Answer (score 0):

The same ininformative message "killed" appears if you're trying to run a 64 bit program on a 32 bit Linux. So my interpretation is that it is a message from the shell if it tried to load a program, and somehow didn't manage to run it.

Comment: If it appears in your xterm window, it's not a message *directly* from the kernel.